# Calling php page from asp.net site on local machine

Tags: php, asp.net, windows, xampp, fastcgi

I have a asp.net website, built in Visual Studio 2010 (MSSQL), Windows 10 OS. I also have XAMPP installed on the machine.

ASP.NET page (random page after login) has a link to a php page. After clicking on the php link, the page is downloaded. ASP.NET site is using MSSQL and php pages are using MySQL. I'm trying to open the link from Visual Studio debugging mode.
I've seen several questions about this, but none of solutions is helping me.

What have I done until now:
- Turned on windows feature CGI (Internet Information Services / World Wide Web Services / Application Development Features / CGI)
- Made changes in php.ini (fastcgi.impersonate = 1, cgi.fix_pathinfo=1, cgi.force_redirect = 0) 
- Added several extensions to php.ini (some of them were not in the xampp package "ext": php_pdo.dll, php_zip.dll, php_pdo_sqlsrv_52_nts_vc6.dll). I have copied files those dlls to xampp/php/etc, but when i'm starting apache, it says it can't find/load dlls (other dlls are loaded corrently, eg. php_mysql.dll)
- changed Listen port in httpd.conf 80 --> 1234
- IIS - I've added Handler Mappings (Request path: *.php / Module: FastCgiModule / Executable: "D:\xampp\php\php-cgi.exe" / Name: PHP via FastCGI) 


- i've run cmd as admin and then exec the following in the c:\WINDOWS\system32 (set config /section:system.webServer/fastCGI /+[fullPath='D:\xampp\php\php-cgi.exe'] AND ALSO set config /section:system.webServer/handlers /+[name='PHP_via_FastCGI',path='*.php',verb='*',modules='FastCgiModule',scriptProcessor='D:\xampp\php\php-cgi.exe',resourceType='Unspecified']) 
- Added php as path: Control Panel / system and aministration / system / advanced system settings / Environment Variables / path / added D:\xampp\php

Is there any hint what can I try to do?

Comment: Why did you change the listening port?

Comment: Because I couldn't start apache via xampp. I presume that IIS was the problem (they are probably using the same port).

Comment: Yes, if IIS is running, the default sites will run on Port 80. Apache would not be able to Listen on 80 if that is the case.